# How to set select2 selected value by text instead of value?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a select2 element with predefined options which means no AJAX call included. In this scenario, I have don't have unique values in select2 but unique text. for example when the page is loaded  I want to set Text '021S-DEFG' as selected value. I have seen quite some answers on SO but still without any workaround to achieve this.

Please note that for this particular case the values of select2 options are same but Text is unique.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js" ></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" />

<select>
  <option value="0">Select something</option>
  <option value="1040">021S-DEFG</option>
  <option value="1040">021S-ABCD</option>

</select>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please change it to a [mcve]

Comment: But first [search your title](https://www.google.com/search?q=select2+set+text+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45169518/2181514

Comment: While the question is closed, if I understand it correctly, you do not want to get an option's text, but set one of the optionsas default when the page loads. If that is correct, you can use `<option value="1040" selected="selected">021S-DEFG</option>` in the markup.

Comment: No, I just quoted the scenario. I am not trying to set a default option rather I am getting a value from backend , the value can be equal to any option in select2 which I have to set as selected. the problem is values of options  are same in several case but different texts.